# How to process inner observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my Angular app is an array `recordlist`. This array contains other arrays of objects. What I'm trying to do now is to process a http.post (via a function) on every nested element in the `recordlist` array.

The `this.recordlist` is an Observable which works and is shown as a table in my app.

```
/**
 *
 */
save() {
    this.recordlist
        .pipe(
            mergeMap((response: any) => response.flat()),
            map((response: any) => {
                console.log('---', response);
                return this.skaterService.setSkaterSeasonBestTimes(response);
            })
        )
        .subscribe(
            response => {},
            error => {},
            () => {
                console.log('.....done');
            }
        );
    }

/**
 *
 */
setSkaterSeasonBestTimes(value: SkaterBesttime): Observable<any> {
    return this.restService.post('/skater/besttimes', value).pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
            console.log('+++', response);
            return new SkaterBesttime(response, true);
        })
    );
}
```

The problem is now that the inner `setSkaterSeasonBestTimes(...)` is not processed. I hope that somebody can give me a useful hint and solution.

Comment: you want to call map on nested call or first call?

Comment: @AakashGarg I want to call setSkaterSeasonBestTimes() on every nested element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed save method :-

```
save() {
    this.recordlist
        .pipe(
            mergeMap((response: any) => {
                let res = response.flat().map((item) => this.setSkaterSeasonBestTimes(item));
                return forkJoin(res);
            })
        )
        .subscribe(
            response => {},
            error => {},
            () => {
                console.log('.....done');
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't work, because ... response.flat()).pipe gives me an error. I also tried to do some of(response.flat()).pipe, but it fails too :-(

Comment: what does response.flat gives?

Comment: mergemap is not for normal response processing

Comment: @AakashGerg I have changed to the code to from(...). now the console.log shows me single elements. BUT the setSkaterSeasonBestTimes() is not processed

Comment: that is not what I'm tying to do. The setSkaterSeasonBestTimes() expects to get a single Object, but not an array (as comes from the code).

Comment: I would need to call setSkaterSeasonBestTimes() on every element of res

Comment: @AakashGerg forkjoin(res) fives me an array Observables. So far so good. But it not processed in subscribe() :-(

Comment: what are you geting in subscribe response?

Comment: that's so strange. In the subscribe comes a single Observale

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214976/discussion-between-aakash-garg-and-lars-hagen).

Answer (score 1):

You reversed your map and your mergeMap.

Try this :

```js
/**
 *
 */
save() {
    this.recordlist
        .pipe(
            map((response: any) => response.flat()),
            mergeMap((response: any) => {
                console.log('---', response);
                return this.skaterService.setSkaterSeasonBestTimes(response);
            })
        )
        .subscribe(
            response => {},
            error => {},
            () => {
                console.log('.....done');
            }
        );
    }

/**
 *
 */
setSkaterSeasonBestTimes(value: SkaterBesttime): Observable<any> {
    return this.restService.post('/skater/besttimes', value).pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
            console.log('+++', response);
            return new SkaterBesttime(response, true);
        })
    );
}
```

mergeMap need to return an Observable